# Creating user in Windows Server 2016

Tags: windows, authentication, ibm-cloud-infrastructure, remote-desktop, windows-server-2016

I have a remote Windows server 2016. With RDP I can login to the server as an Administrator.

I created a new user with Admin rights and also with Remote access enabled. But I am unable to login via RDP with the new user.

I have created the user via Computer Managment-> Users and Groups

Comment: please let me know what is missing in the question. So that i can edit the question accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The created user should also be added to the Remote Desktop Users Group so as to give the users permission to access the machine remotely.